# external usb drive vanished from ubuntu 16.04 during long file operations

Tags: 16.04, usb, external-hdd, copy

During big file copy ops, after it ran for hours somewhen in the night, the drive just vanished from ubuntu. I checked on the syslog and found out that at 4:54am the device disconnected. there are lots of other errors in the log, also.

unfortunately i am new to ubuntu, so can anybody have a look at the syslog and can tell me what has happened and how i can get the device stay available in ubuntu?

i would provide the syslog, but i don't know how to attach a file here.

Comment: restartet laptop copied again some hours and exactly the same happened again. so i am without a clue. please help.

Comment: no one any idea?

Comment: please, this really is annoying. thank you so much.